# memory full but not garbage collection

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I have a problem that: Eden 100% used,Old 100% used,From Space 100% used,but not garbage collection triggered, no oom

jmap -heap [pid] result

```
Eden Space:    
capacity = 859045888 (819.25MB)    
used     = 859045888(819.25MB)   
free     = 0 (0.0MB)
100.0% used 
From Space:    
capacity = 107347968 (102.375MB)    
used     = 12370032(11.796981811523438MB)    
free     = 16441280 (90.57801818847656MB)
0.0% used 
To Space:    
capacity = 107347968 (102.375MB)   
used     = 0 (0.0MB)    
free     = 107347968 (102.375MB)
 0.0% used 
PS Old generation:    
capacity = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)   
used     = 1073741816 (1023.0832290649414MB)    
free     = 8 (7.62399453125E-6MB)
 99.99999925494154% used 
Perm Generation:    
capacity = 268435456 (256.0MB)    
used     = 79784056 (76.08800506591797MB)    
free     = 188651400 (179.91199493408203MB)
 29.721876978874207% used

jstat -gcutil [pid] 1000
   S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC   YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  11.52  0.00  100.00  100.00  30.28  22   5.87     3    6.136    11.723
  11.52  0.00  100.00  100.00  30.28  22   5.87     3    6.136    11.723
  11.52  0.00  100.00  100.00  30.28  22   5.87     3    6.136    11.723
  11.52  0.00  100.00  100.00  30.28  22   5.87     3    6.136    11.723
  11.52  0.00  100.00  100.00  30.28  22   5.87     3    6.136    11.723
  11.52  0.00  100.00  100.00  30.28  22   5.87     3    6.136    11.723
```

My vm args is

> -Xmx2g -Xms2g -Xmn1g -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=128m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=0 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80

How to solve it ?

Comment: Why you say there is no GC. Please add `-Xloggc:/path/to/file` and adds the content. Have you tried to attach visual vm for example?

Comment: Either you managed, in the above hodge-podge of options, to muck up GC, or you are allocating a lot of stuff that you never let go unreferenced.  Or you're not having a storage problem at all and some other error is occurring.  (You didn't list any error.)

Answer (score 1):

Why such complicated `jvm parameters` (you are missing `-Xloggc:/path/to/file` to avoid just verbose logging).

I find really hard to believe that no `GC` is being triggered. If I were you would start with a more easy to understand options, and from there iterate. Bear in mind that in most of the cases just setting `Xms` and `Xmx` is enough. As `heap` is based on ratios and the ergonomics do the rest.